# Double Integration quandrant

Tags: integration

Could somebody please explain to me how I am supposed to find the double integral of $f(x,y)=x^2y^2$ on the region $R$, where $R$ is the bounded portion of the first quadrant lying between the two hyperbolae $xy=1$ and $xy=2$ and the two lines $y=x$ and $y=4x$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Divide your portion in three parts by special vertical lines.

Comment: use polar coordinates

Comment: I think the most direct way would be to perform a change of variables using the transformation $x=u/v$, $y=uv$, the general method for which is described in detail here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx.

(If you happen to have access to *Multivariable Calculus: Early Transcendentals*, third edition, by Rogawski and Adams, you should consult section 15.6.)